ffmpeg x11grab on ubuntu: increase FPS
I am trying to configure FFMpeg to capture whole FHD screen (browser with videos inside and sounds). The result has too low FPS (from 3 to 15 per second, depending on CLI params, but i need at least 30 frames per second).
Only firefox and ffmpeg are running while the screen is recorded, no other apps loaded. Browser renders content without lags, everything works smoothly as I can see on display.
Current version of OS is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Lubuntu distro), I've tried different: 20.04, 22.04, 24.04 – with the same result.
Here is the hardware I got: 8GB RAM, CPU:
Vendor ID:                          GenuineIntel
CPU family:                         6
Model:                              142
Model name:                         Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:                           9
CPU MHz:                            2700.000
CPU max MHz:                        3100.0000
CPU min MHz:                        400.0000

Video adapter:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915

description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:125 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

I got SSD, AHCI enabled, speed test results below:
$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   14394 MB in  1.99 seconds = 7232.49 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1552 MB in  3.00 seconds = 517.09 MB/sec

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=8k count=10k; rm -f /tmp/output
10240+0 records in
10240+0 records out
83886080 bytes (84 MB, 80 MiB) copied, 0.0493025 s, 1.7 GB/s

I watched CPU temperature while capture being made, it's ok
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

Also when I watch at top command, each CPU core load is about 50% (I expected about 100%).
I tried to enable/disable hyper-threading in BIOS – no difference.
Here is the log of ffmpeg:
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[x11grab @ 0x618d6e2979c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0+420,0+nomouse':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1714673470.543033, bitrate: 1119744 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1080x1080, 1119744 kb/s, 30 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, pulse, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1714673470.670193, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x618d6e2b1300] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x618d6e2b1300] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.2, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x618d6e2b1300] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=0 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=0
Output #0, matroska, to '/home/gena2/rvideosrv/storage/salEh99z/salEh99z.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv444p(tv, progressive), 1080x1080, q=2-31, 30 fps, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 pcm_s16le
[x11grab @ 0x618d6e2979c0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame=  595 fps=4.1 q=0.0 size=  299264kB time=00:02:2frame=  618 fps=4.1 q=0.0 size=  310272kB time=00:02:31.75 bitrate=16748.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=51 speed=0.999x

Below are the command variants that I've tried:
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0+0,0+nomouse -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -c:a pcm_s16le -y /home/user/cJE2wDqU.mkv

ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0+0,0+nomouse -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -b:a 320k -b:v 10M -ac 96000 -preset ultrafast -threads 2 -y /home/user/cJE2wDqU.mkv

I tried to set threads 4, tried to set crf, thread_queue_size, probesize, b:v – without any results.
May be I should install codecs or something?

Try: ffmpeg -hide_banner -threads 0 -f x11grab -i "$DISPLAY" -s 1920x1080 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -c:a pcm_s16le -y /home/user/cJE2wDqU.mkv Check out this post, also.

@JayCravens your command has errors inside. and the reason was not in CLI params but in codecs, i've built ffmpeg with QSV (intel sync video) codecs, and FPS became great

Well, the codec my vary, certainly.  It is a working command, though, provided you want libx264.

After a few days of research and tests, I've solved the problem.
The answer is to compile FFMpeg with QSV (Intel sync video) codecs (hardware acceleration).
The link to manual is here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/728030/building-ffmpeg-with-qsv-on-windows-and-linux-intel-platform.html?wapkw=ffmpeg
But there are some issues in the PDF, so I will post CLI commands here as well:
sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libtool pkg-config texinfo zlib1g-dev libva-dev cmake mercurial libdrm-dev libvorbis-dev libogg-dev git libx11-dev libperl-dev libpciaccess-dev libpciaccess0 xorg-dev intel-gpu-tools opencl-headers libwayland-dev xutils-dev ocl-icd-* libssl-dev

mkdir -p ~/vaapi/workspace
mkdir -p ~/ffmpeg_build
mkdir -p ~/ffmpeg_sources
mkdir -p ~/bin

cd ~/vaapi
wget https://github.com/intel/libva/archive/refs/tags/2.13.0.tar.gz -O libva.tar.gz
tar zxf libva.tar.gz --one-top-level=libva --strip-components 1
cd libva
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
make -j$(nproc) VERBOSE=1
sudo make -j$(nproc) install
sudo ldconfig -vvvv

cd ~/vaapi/workspace
wget https://github.com/intel/gmmlib/archive/refs/tags/intel-gmmlib-22.0.1.tar.gz
tar zxf intel-gmmlib-22.0.1.tar.gz --one-top-level=gmmlib --strip-components 1
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE= Release ../gmmlib
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make -j$(nproc) install

cd ~/vaapi/workspace
wget https://github.com/intel/media-driver/archive/refs/tags/intel-media-22.1.1.tar.gz
tar zxf intel-media-22.1.1.tar.gz --one-top-level=media-driver --strip-components 1
cd media-driver
mkdir -p ~/vaapi/workspace/build_media
cd ~/vaapi/workspace/build_media
cmake ../media-driver \
-DBS_DIR_GMMLIB=$PWD/../gmmlib/Source/GmmLib/ \
-DBS_DIR_COMMON=$PWD/../gmmlib/Source/Common/ \
-DBS_DIR_INC=$PWD/../gmmlib/Source/inc/ \
-DBS_DIR_MEDIA=$PWD/../media-driver \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
-DINSTALL_DRIVER_SYSCONF=OFF \
-DLIBVA_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make -j$(nproc) install

Now, export environment variables as shown below, or you can declare them to ~/.bashrc
LIBVA_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=iHD

cd ~/vaapi
wget https://github.com/intel/libva-utils/archive/refs/tags/2.13.0.tar.gz -O libva-utils.tar.gz
tar zxf libva-utils.tar.gz --one-top-level=libva-utils --strip-components 1
cd libva-utils
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make -j$(nproc) install

https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/tag/22.01.22131

cd ~/vaapi
wget https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/archive/refs/tags/intel-mediasdk-22.1.0.tar.gz
tar zxf intel-mediasdk-22.1.0.tar.gz --one-top-level=MediaSDK --strip-components 1
cd MediaSDK
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ../
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make -j$(nproc) install

When the above is done, please issue a reboot!!!

sudo reboot

cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.14.02/nasm-2.14.02.tar.gz
tar xzvf nasm-2.14.02.tar.gz
cd nasm-2.14.02
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin"
make -j$(nproc) VERBOSE=1
make -j$(nproc) install
make -j$(nproc) distclean

cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
git clone http://git.videolan.org/git/x264.git
cd x264
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --enable-static --enable-pic --bit-depth=all
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make -j$(nproc) VERBOSE=1
make -j$(nproc) install VERBOSE=1
make -j$(nproc) distclean

cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources/FFmpeg
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/intel/mediasdk/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
--pkg-config-flags="--static" \
--enable-static --disable-shared \
--prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
--bindir="$HOME/bin" \
--extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
--extra-cflags="-I/opt/intel/mediasdk/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L/opt/intel/mediasdk/lib" \
--extra-ldflags="-L/opt/intel/mediasdk/plugins" \
--enable-libmfx \
--enable-vaapi \
--enable-opencl \
--disable-debug \
--enable-libdrm \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-runtime-cpudetect \
--enable-libx264 \
--enable-libpulse \
--enable-libfdk-aac \
--enable-libfreetype \
--enable-libmp3lame \
--enable-libvorbis \
--enable-openssl \
--enable-pic \
--extra-libs="-lpthread -lm -lz -ldl" \
--enable-nonfree
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make -j$(nproc)
make -j$(nproc) install
make -j$(nproc) distclean
hash -r

And finally the command to record screen:
ffmpeg -f x11grab -hwaccel qsv -framerate 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0+0,0+nomouse -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast -crf 0 -c:a pcm_s16le -y /home/gena/video.mkv

